# Present view controller from NSObject subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableView whose delegate and data source is in a different file. When tapping a row, in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` a new view controller should be pushed on stack. Since the NSObject file (which contains the UITableView delegate and data source) doesn't have `presentViewController:animated:completion:` I can't push a new view controller.

I figured there are two ways to fix this.

### Option 1:

Adding a property of the tableview's view controller (`RootViewController`) to the NSObject file and setting that property equal to the view controller when initializing the object. That way I could do this in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[self.rootVC presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

### Option 2:

I could also add a delegate to the NSObject file which does the logic of changing view controllers in `RootViewController`.

```
@protocol YBMatchesTableViewDelegateAndDataSourceDelegate
@optional

-(void)rowTapped;

@end

@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
```

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` `[self.delegate rowTapped];`. Finally, in RootViewController.

```
-(void)rowTapped {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**What doesn't work:**

- `[[RootViewController new] presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];`
- Subclassing `RootViewController` and putting the tableview's delegate and data source in there.

Both say it is not in the view hierarchy. `Warning: Attempt to present <DetailViewController 0x109123ff0> on <RootViewController: 0x10912aef0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Which one would you prefer? Or which one should I absolutely *not* use? I incline to go for the delegate since the first one gets me another property/object.

Comment: Could you expand on option 2?  I think that's probably the best option, but I want to be more clear how you intend to do that.

Comment: How do you put your table view on the screen? Are you using a controller for that, i.e. a kind of UIViewController? That would be the object responsible for presenting the new view controller as well.

Comment: Nope, just create a UITableView programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with **option 2**. It means that your delegate and datasource doesn't need to hold a reference to a viewcontroller just so that it can present another viewcontroller. It's also an extra separation of responsibility - your delegate / datasource is only responsible for managing the tableview's data, *not* for performing UI functionality / navigation when the user selects something.

By implementing a delegate, your `YBMatchesTableViewDelegateAndDataSource` remains about the *data*. It simply reports when the user has selected a piece of data. Your viewcontroller can then decide how to manage views to deal with that.

I would recommend renaming your `rowTapped` method, though. I'd make it more descriptive, and depending on your setup you might want to pass a parameter so that your viewcontroller knows what content it needs to display. Something like:

```
- (void)userDidSelectMatch:(YBMatch *)match;
```

or something similar (just guessing at your data structure, there), might be a bit more meaningful?

Comment: Exactly what I figured. The `rowTapped` method was just for example purposes.