# Protocols and Delegates not working with UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a section footer enabled. I have created a custom subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` called `LeafletFooterView` and declared some `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s:

```
- (IBAction)dropboxButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)soundcloudButton:(id)sender;
```

In my `UICollectionViewClass`, I have:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        UICollectionReusableView *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

In the `IBAction` of the `LeafletFooterView` class, I am simply trying to present another `viewController`:

```
- (IBAction)dropboxButton:(id)sender
{
    VideoWebViewController *video = [[VideoWebViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:video];

    [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];

    [video setSelectedVideo:@"https://www.dropbox.com/"];
}
```

The error is:

```
No visible @interface for 'LeafletFooterView' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion'.
```

I have tried     `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.dropbox.com"]];` in the `IBAction` method and although now there are no errors, clicking on it doesn't open Safari with the website. The method is definitely called; a `NSLog` and `Breakpoint` prove that.

**Update**

So after that didn't work, I tried to go through the process of declaring Delegates for this, much in the same way this question does: [Present view controller from NSObject subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369497/present-view-controller-from-nsobject-subclass).

Here's my `LeafletFooterView`:

```
@class LeafletFooterView;
@protocol FooterViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)rowTapped;
@end
@interface LeafletFooterView : UICollectionReusableView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
- (IBAction)dropboxButton:(id)sender;
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<FooterViewDelegate> delegate;

The LeafletFooterView.m is here: - (IBAction)dropboxButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Dropbox");
    [self.delegate rowTapped];
}
```

Now in my `LeafletCollectionViewController`, I have:

```
- (void)rowTapped
{
    NSLog(@"Is this getting called?");
    VideoWebViewController *video = [[VideoWebViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:video];

    [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];

    [video setSelectedVideo:@"https://www.dropbox.com/"];

}
```

When I run this code, this method never actually gets called. The `LeafletCollectionView` is set to use the `FooterViewDelegate`. In the `viewWillAppear` of the `LeafletCollectionView`, I tried the following:

```
LeafletFooterView *footer = [[LeafletFooterView alloc] init];
footer.delegate = self;
```

Still the `rowTapped` method never actually gets called.

The user should be able to click on the `UIButton` in the `LeafletFooterView` and for it to present the `UIViewController`. How do I go about achieving this? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to present the `UINavigationController` where your `dataSource` is.  So if you try removing that `IBAction` and instead programatically adding a method to wherever your dataSource is to present the `VideoWebViewController`.

Then in your `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method you'd access the button and fire that method.  So off the top of my head (haven't used objC in a while):

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        LeafletFooterView *footerview = (LeafletFooterView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [footerView.dropboxButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(dropboxTapped:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}

-(void)dropboxTapped:(id)sender{
    // Present the controller here
}
```

I hope this helps :)

EDIT: After updating your question, I see that you've gone a different route.  You just need to set the delegate for the footerView, like this:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        LeafletFooterView *footerview = (LeafletFooterView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [footerView.dropboxButton addTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(dropboxTapped:)
                           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        footerView.delegate = self
        reusableview = footerview;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

Also, don't forget to cast the view to `LeafletFooterView` like I did in the code using `(LeafletFooterView *)` I hope that works :)

Comment: Thanks man - that's super helpful and that makes sense. I'm just not too sure on the "So if you try removing that IBAction and instead programmatically adding a method to whoever your dataSource is to present the VideoWebViewController".. I'm not too sure what to do there

Comment: @amitsbajaj sure, delete the IBAction (in interface builder, where you click the button, then the outlets, then the cross for the action), then try the code above

Comment: Hey @daven - sorry - I thought the code worked, but I was explicitly calling the method for a test and I had forgotten to take that code out. This code here generates an error for me in your answer because footerView doesn't have a reference to .dropboxButton, etc. In any case, I've had to reopen the case here. I've updated my question with the use of Delegates to try get this working. Alternatively, if you're able to update your answer with reference to how to call the dropboxButton , etc, that might work as well. Thanks again!

Comment: THAT worked like a charm! the footerView.delegate was the key here because I was setting that delegate at the wrong place and with a breakpoint, it just kept showing that the delegate was zero. That works like a charm and that is really helpful! Thank man - definitely accepting and up-voting :)